# BigQuery Firebase Average Coins Per Level In The Game

Tags: sql, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery

I developed a words game (using firebase as my backend) with levels and coins. 
Now, I'm facing some difficulties while trying to query my DB, so that it will output a table with all levels in the game and average user coins for each level. For example :

```
Level     Avg User Coins
0             50
1             12
2             2
```

Attached is a picture of my events table:
[image]

So as you can see, there is an event of 'level_end', then we can see the 'user coins' and 'level_num'. What is the right way to do that?

This is what I managed to do so far, obviously the wrong way :

```
SELECT event_name,user_id
FROM `words-game-en.analytics_208527783.events_20191004`,
  UNNEST(event_params) as event_param
WHERE event_name = "level_end"
AND event_param.key = "user_coins"
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the structure of the table you are using, including the nested `struct` and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT event_param.level_num, AVG(event_param.user_coins)
FROM `words-game-en.analytics_208527783.events_20191004` CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(event_params) as event_param
WHERE event_name = 'level_end' AND event_param.key = 'user_coins'
GROUP BY level_num
ORDER BY level_num;
```

I'm a little confused by what is in `event_params` and what is directly in events, so you might need to properly qualify the column references.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it complains about : "Unrecognized name: level_num at [1:8]",  'level_num' and 'user_coins' are one level inside, maybe this is the reason it is not recognize them?

Comment: @אברגיליעקובו . . . That would be why they are not recognized.

Comment: I tried this already, but it's still complaining : 
"Field name level_num does not exist in STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>> at [1:20]".  Seems like UNNEST need to be used here